# Get the rows of my output sorted in ascending order from this table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have the following table (`t1`) which contains around 5,000 rows.
Here is an extract of `t1`:

```
 n1   n2   n3   n4   n5   n6  Type
 6    15   10   11   22   25   C1
 2     5    1   20   21   30   C1
15    25   18    4   12   38   C2
11     1    4    9   24   31   C2
...
```

I need select all the rows from the table but I want the output to be sorted in ascending for each row.

Here is the expected output:

```
 Nr1   Nr2   Nr3  Nr4   Nr5  Nr6   Type
  6    10    11   15    22   25     C1
  1     2     5   20    21   30     C1
  4    12    15   18    25   38     C2
  1     4     9   11    24   31     C2
  ...
```

I know how to `ORDER BY` columns but I am completely stuck as to how to approach this problem. Do I need to `pivot` the data, sort it and then unpivot it to achieve this?

Note: I have added an Id column to my column. Each row now has a unique Id (1,2,3,...)

My attempt as per Menno's Solution:

```
;with cte1 as (

SELECT [id], [type], Col, Val
FROM (  
  SELECT [id], [n1], [n2], [n3], [n4], [n5], [n6], [type]
  FROM [t1] ) t
UNPIVOT
   (Col FOR Val IN ([n1], [n2], [n3], [n4], [n5], [n6]))
AS tblUnPivot

),

cte2 as (

Select

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Val) OrderedVals, * 

from [cte1]

),

cte3 as (

SELECT [id], [type], Col, Val
FROM (  
  SELECT [OrderedVals], [id], [type], [Col]
  FROM [cte2] ) s
PIVOT
   (??? FOR OrderedVals IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]))

AS tblPivot

)

select * from [cte3]
```

Comment: Seems like an XY problem, in my opinion. Moving the values in the columns changes the values of the row. You're not reordering the columns here, your actually changing the data.

Comment: Does your table at *least* have a unique column?

Comment: @Larnu Yes I have added the Id column to the table. Not shown in my question. I did it afterwards following Menno's solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Assuming** that there is some kind of ID column, then you can unpivot the values, and the Pivot them back using `VALUES` and a Cross Tab:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int IDENTITY, --Required to work
                            n1 tinyint,
                            n2 tinyint,
                            n3 tinyint,
                            n4 tinyint,
                            n5 tinyint,
                            n6 tinyint,
                            [Type] char(2));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (n1,n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, [Type])
VALUES( 6,15,10,11,22,25,'C1'),
      ( 2, 5, 1,20,21,30,'C1'),
      (15,25,18, 4,12,38,'C2'),
      (11, 1, 4, 9,24,31,'C2');

GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;

WITH unPvt AS (
    SELECT YT.ID,
           YT.[Type],
           V.Val,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YT.ID ORDER BY V.Val) AS NewPos
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(1,YT.n1),
                            (2,YT.n2),
                            (3,YT.n3),
                            (4,YT.n4),
                            (5,YT.n5),
                            (6,YT.n6))V(Pos,Val))
SELECT MAX(CASE NewPos WHEN 1 THEN Val END) AS n1,
       MAX(CASE NewPos WHEN 2 THEN Val END) AS n2,
       MAX(CASE NewPos WHEN 3 THEN Val END) AS n3,
       MAX(CASE NewPos WHEN 4 THEN Val END) AS n4,
       MAX(CASE NewPos WHEN 5 THEN Val END) AS n5,
       MAX(CASE NewPos WHEN 6 THEN Val END) AS n6,
       [Type]
FROM unPvt
GROUP BY ID,[Type]
ORDER BY [Type];


GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

- You could give each row an unique ID, for example: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) ID`
- Then you could unpivot your data, for example: `Col FOR Val IN ([Nr1], [Nr2], [Nr3], [Nr4], [Nr5], [Nr 6])`
- Then order the value per ID, for example: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Val) OrderedVals`
- Then pivot your data `FOR OrderedVals IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])`

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question with my attempt based on your solution but I am stuck at the PIVOT step. Can you please have a look?

Comment: Also, in your proposed solution, you use [Nr1], [Nr2], ... but I get an error when using those values. Using [n1], [n2],... don't give an error. Is that the way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to Larnu's answer, but it should  have better performance *because it is avoiding aggregation over the entire table*.   In addition, it returns the same rows as in the original data without introducing a fake `id`.

Yyou can aggregate within the `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT v.*, t.type
FROM t CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN n END) as n1,
             MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN n END) as n2,
             MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN n END) as n3,
             MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 4 THEN n END) as n4,
             MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 5 THEN n END) as n5,
             MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 6 THEN n END) as n6
      FROM (SELECT v.n,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) as seqnum
            FROM (VALUES (t.n1), (t.n2), (t.n3), (t.n4), (t.n5), (t.n6)
                 ) v(n)
           ) v
     ) v;
```

Comment: I actually find, on my home system that mine is faster (by a large margin), Gordon. Unfortunately, DB Fiddle shows the opposite; so it might well be a "it depends".

Comment: @larnu . . . Interesting.  I do think on large data this should scale better.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code without use pivot

```
DECLARE @T 
TABLE(n1 INT, n2 INT, n3 INT, n4 INT, n5 INT, n6 INT,Type VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @T(n1,   n2,   n3,   n4,   n5,   n6,  Type)
      SELECT  6  ,  15  , 10  , 11 , 22  , 25  , 'C1'
UNION SELECT  2  ,  5   , 1   , 20 , 21  , 30  , 'C1'
UNION SELECT  15 ,  25  , 18  , 4  , 12  , 38  , 'C2'
UNION SELECT  11 ,  1   , 4   , 9  , 24  , 31  , 'C2'

SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ord=1 THEN n ELSE 0 END) AS Nr1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ord=2 THEN n ELSE 0 END) AS Nr2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ord=3 THEN n ELSE 0 END) AS Nr3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ord=4 THEN n ELSE 0 END) AS Nr4,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ord=5 THEN n ELSE 0 END) AS Nr5,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ord=6 THEN n ELSE 0 END) AS Nr6,
       Type
FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER by Type) as unq
      FROM @T
)AS IndexedT
CROSS APPLY(SELECT n , ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER by n) as ord
            FROM (      SELECT n1 as n 
                  UNION SELECT n2       
                  UNION SELECT n3      
                  UNION SELECT n4       
                  UNION SELECT n5       
                  UNION SELECT n6      
            )as X
) AS PivotItem
GROUP BY unq,Type
```